# how to make sql server 2005 search in arabic language?

Tags: asp.net

I have a SQL Server 2005 database in which I have some tables contain Arabic text. The datatype for those fields is NVARCHAR(n).

The Arabic text inside the table is appearing properly, and when selecting using select clause, they appear properly. 
The problem is that searching for Arabic text with where clause results in 0 rows.

select * from table_name
where name=@name

This retrieves no rows, where there is a name with this value. 
When we use it like:

select * from table_name
where name=N’Arabic_Text’

Then it works, but how we can pass searching text from front end to back end.
Can you please guide me on how to write the query?

**PS**

In code behind i wrote:

```
Dim UserName As String = "N'" & txtLogin.Text & "'"
Dim _dtLogin As DataTable = oUser.UserLogin(UserName)
```

it returns 0 rows even if that user exist in database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your query and you need to use N before value to check because of unicode value

Answer (score 0):

Considering this part: `select * from table_name where name=@name`

If this is a stored procedure, you need to modify it to be like this:

```
select * from table_name where name=N@name
```

give it a try and let us know if it worked.

Comment: ya i have already tried it but it giving following error: Invalid column name 'N@UserName'.

Comment: I think you have made it wrong, this errors will not occure if you follow my suggestion, your error is in the part BEFORE the = sign, not after.
kindly double check again.

Comment: I think declaring the input parameter as NVARCHAR should return the correct values. Is the stored procedure returning values without the  N (name=@name) ?